# Do Vedas mention the various people holding the title of Manu?

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, time, manu, manvantara

Many people would be aware that Manu, like Indra, is not the name of a person but a title that is passed on to different people from time to time (to be specific, after a Manvantar). It is also believed that the Vedas have come down to us unchanged from the beginning of time. So ideally, judging by their eternal nature, they should not contain the names of different people holding the same title since that would point to interpolations at different times.

However, an article on [this site](https://tamilandvedas.com/2015/01/19/mystery-of-manu-rig-veda-mystery-no-8/) mentions that Rigveda gives the names of the following historical Manus:

> Saaryaata Maanava RV 10-92
>
> Cakshu Maanava 9-52, 9-106-4
>
> Manu Vaivasvata – 8-5, 8-27-31
>
> Manu Samvrana 9-49, 9-101-10
>
> Manyu Tapasa – 10-67, 10-83,84

I could not find any reference to these Manus in the said verses so **I would like to know if the various Manus of previous eras are indeed mentioned in any of the Vedic verses.**

Comment: Manyu is actually name of a rudra.

Comment: I know but the question is about Manus - Tapasa is also one of the Manus.

Comment: Are you looking for Samhitas only or we can give references from Upanishads and Brahmanas too?

Comment: I was more concerned with the particular references this guy gave in the article but please feel free to mention any references from the entire Vedic corpus. If these guys are really mentioned it could mean the Vedas were put down in current form in the Vaivasvat Manvantar.

Comment: I think references are not right. Also I cannot find what is `8-27-31`?

Comment: Yes that's what I concluded as well. Anyhow please do share if you do find some references of any of these Manus being mentioned.

Comment: Rig Veda 10.83.2 `मन्युं विश ईळते मानुषीर्याः पाहि नोमन्यो तपसा सजोषाः ||` It mention Tapasaa not Taapasa and the translation is also not clear.

Comment: Hmmm yes seems to be more related to Manyu than Tapas Manu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not able to figure out those references mentioned in question. So, I am answering only this part:

#### would like to know if these Manus of previous eras are indeed mentioned in any of the Vedic verses including four parts of Veda

1. Manu Vaivasvata is mentioned at some places in Vedic literature.

   - > She mounted up, she came to men. They called her, Come unto-
     >   us, come hither thou Free-giver!
     >   Earth was her milking-pail, the calf beside her **Manu Vaivasvata**,
     >   **Vivasvān's offspring**.
     >   Prithi the son of Vena was her milker: he milked forth hus-
     >   bandry and grain for sowing.
     >   These men depend for life on corn and tillage. He who knows
     >   this becomes a meet supporter, successful in the culture of his_
     >   corn-land. [Atharva Veda, Book 8, Hymn 10](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av08010.htm)
   - > 'King **Manu Vaivasvata**,' he says;--'his people are Men, and they are staying here;' [Satapatha Brahmana, Thirteenth Kanda, Fourth Adhyaya, Third Brahmana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe44/sbe44104.htm)
2. Manu Samvrana

   - > As with **Manu Samvarani**, Indra, thou drankest Soma juice,
     >   And, Maghavan, with Nipatithi, Medbyatithi, with Pustigu and Srustigu,— [Rig Veda, Book 8, Hymn III](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv08095.htm)
   - > And these commended horses, bright and active, by Dhvanya son of Laksmana presented,
     >   Came unto me, as cows into the **Ṛṣi Samvarana's** stall, with magnitude of riches. [Rig Veda, Book 5, HYMN XXXIII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv05033.htm)
3. Saryata Manu

   - > 17 Wherewith Paṭharvā, in his majesty of form, shone in his course like to a gathered kindled fire;
     >   Wherewith ye helped **Śāryāta** in the mighty fray,—Come hither unto us, O Aśvins, with those aids. [Rig Veda, Book 1, HYMN CXII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01112.htm)
   - > 2. But **Saryâta, the Mânava**, just then wandered about here with his tribe, and settled near by that same place. His boys 1, while playing, setting that decrepit, ghostlike man at nought, pelted him with clods. [Satapatha Brahmana, Fourth Kanda, First Adhyaya, Fifth Brahmana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe26/sbe2644.htm)

<sub>I will update with others when found.</sub>

Comment: Nice.. its a good beginning. I am searching too lets see whether we can actually find their names or not.

Answer (score 0):

[Manu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manu_(Hinduism)#Manus_of_the_current_kalpa) is the title or name of fourteen  Kshatriya rulers of earth, or alternatively as the head of mythical dynasties that begin with each cyclic kalpa  when the universe is born anew.

Manu as a King appears in post Vedic Literature.

---

1) Manu Samvarani, as stated to have been  mentioned in [Rig Veda, Book 8, Hymn III](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv08003.htm), in another answer, **could not be located**.

2) In the other 2 Hymns, ie., Rig Veda, Book 5, HYMN XXXIII and Rig Veda, Book 1, HYMN CXII, in which Manu Samvrana and Saryata Manu were stated to have been mentioned in another answer, appears to be referring to Rishies but not Kings.

---

It does not mean to say that there was no mention of Manu in Rig Veda.

Rig Veda II.20.7 says

> sa vṛtrahendraḥ kṛṣṇayonīḥ purandaro dāsīrairayad vi | ajanayan manave
>   kṣāmapaśca satrā śaṃsaṃ yajamānasya tūtot ||
>
> Indra the Vṛtra-slayer, Fort-destroyer, scattered the Dāsa hosts who
>   dwelt in darkness. **For Manu hath he created earth and waters**, and ever
>   helped the prayer of him who worships.

This Mantra says **Indra**, but not Vishnu or Brahma,  **created Earth and waters** for Manu.

However, it is not clearly coming forth from the above mantra whether this Manu is the same as that mentioned in Puranas.

---

Comment: Yes I havent been able to find these specific names as well hence the question